# Spring Security - Preauthentication - Authorization and Set Roles Defined in DB

Tags: spring-security, roles, pre-authentication

The authentication for our application happens through siteminder agent but the authorization is controlled through our application.

I am using org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter to check the header. I have also defined UserDetailsService to load the user details.

I also need to set the role for the user so that I can use spring security tag libraries and other spring methods to check the role and show the options.

How do I implement this?

I have tried the below statements in my user details service implementation, but doesn't seem to work.

```
    Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, roles);
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
```

I have also read about AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter class but looks like this is may not be useful for this purpose.

Any help on this issue will be very helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: Your _RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter_ extends the _AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter_ that you are talking about. You're good there. But you also need to set up the _PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider_. You'll need to provide your security config files for someone to help you better.

Comment: Thank you for the response Angad. I was using PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider provided by Spring Security, but was not extending it to set the roles.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to set the roles(using the statements in my question) in the UserDetailsService 
implementation and it was not working.

Solution-1:
I have written a sub class PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider and overridden the authenticate method as below :

```
public class CustomPreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider extends PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider {


    @Autowired
    DBConfig dbConfig;

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication)throws AuthenticationException {
        Authentication auth = super.authenticate(authentication);

        User user = (User)auth.getPrincipal();

        Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<Role>();

        String[] rolesArray = dbConfig.getRoles(user.getAccessLevel());
        for(String role: rolesArray){
            Role r = new Role();
            r.setName(role);
            roles.add(r);
        }

        user.setRoles(roles);

        auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, roles);

        return auth;
    }


}
```

Solution-2 : 
I tried setting the roles in the controller (the home page after authentication) and it worked. But looks like Solution-1 is a standard solution.

Comment: Solution-1 is obviously preferable. I prefer keeping the roles fetch logic in UserDetailsService though. For that, what you would need is to implement the Spring provided class _AuthenticationUserDetailsService_ with generic type _PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken_ and override _loadUserDetails()_ method to write your roles logic